# Why can't I first declare and initialize windows forms objects and have them appear on the designer tab?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am making a basic windows forms app in C# on Visual Studio. Even after declaring two buttons in 'form1.Designer.cs' by copying the exact syntax that it adds to the file when you drag a button onto the 'form1.cs[design]' tab.

I wanted to code it first and then make it appear on the actual designer tab. I was able to declare button objects in the code file and even tried specifying new locations since I thought maybe the locations were out of scope of the forms coordinates but they didn't appear anywhere. I finally had to drag two new buttons and they obviously appeared on the 'form1.Designer.cs' file so now I had 5 buttons declared and had to delete the code that I manually wrote for the buttons. How to make them appear on 'form1.cs[Design]' after first coding the objects in 'form1.Designer.cs.'?

Comment: The designer is written around the InitializeComponent method. So if you change something directly in that method it should be taken up by the designer.

Comment: Declaring is not enough. You must add them to a `Controls` collection. Either the form's collection or container control's collection. `Controls.Add(button1);`.

Comment: Without seeing your code, we cannot tell you what's wrong with it.